# Is the MyoRing operation a successful treatment for Keratoconus?

Tags: medical-science, healthcare, ophthalmology

[Keratoconus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keratoconus) is a disease that causes progressive (and irregular) thinning of the cornea.

[MyoRing](https://www.dioptex.com/products/myoring-corneal-implant/) is an treatment that involves implanting a ring under the cornea. It supposedly improves vision by a lot and also halts / slows the disease progression.

This is a pretty new operation and there seems to still be very little (independent) science on the matter. Most studies are by the (only) doctor and inventor of this method, [Dr. Albert Daxer](https://www.cisis.com/en/doctors/dr-albert-daxer/).

I have found [one study](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6043/241930aca736c8c380b38aeed7664dedc2e3.pdf) not connected to Daxer.

I'm not really proficient in determining if the results of the study are actually a big improvement or if the numbers and scales are just set-up to look good.

Is MyoRing a successful treatment of Keratoconus?

Comment: I can't decide if these links need some sort of warning to the squeamish that they show opthamology photos.

Comment: @Oddthinking you want to protect their... _eyes?_ :)